# Setting objects equal without pointing to the same reference point

Tags: java

How can I set one object equal to another without causing the objects to change when one is changed. For example, if I had object1 and object2, and object1=object2, then anything I do to object2 will also be done to object1 since they are pointing to the same reference point. So I am asking how to set object1=object2 in a way that changing the values of object2 won't affect object1. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have?

Comment: Please edit out the irrelevant code so that >>we<< don't have to read it!

Comment: I edited to post so it only asks the question directly now.

Comment: You'd have to set `object1` to reference a second object which is a **copy** of what `object2` references.  Then, `object1 != object2`, but (provided you've properly defined the `equals` method for that type of object) `object1.equals(object2)`.  If you then modified `object2`, the instance referenced by `object1` would be unaffected (the instances referenced by `object1` and `object2` would, of course, then no longer be "equal").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign `object1 = object2` then the variables refer to the identical object.

You want a separate object that is equal to the first one.  Typically, `object1 = object2.clone()` would make a copy, but that depends on object2 being cloneable.

Comment: How can you determine if an object is cloneable?

Comment: Look at the source code: ```class FooBar implements Cloneable``` or read the documentation.  An alternative I should also have mentioned is the "copy constructor" -- ```object1 = new FooBar(object2)```; again see documentation.